# USB Mounts in Linux

Tags: linux, usb, mount

I am running CentOS 5.  I have connected a USB device (a Serial <-> USB connector).  The device is "detected" (in `/proc/bus/usb/devices` ... the device is clearly there).

Also, if I do lsusb, I see the device name.

Does this mean that CentOS has detected the device and now I can use it? So in this case, it no longer an operating system issue, but a library issue to run the device?

Comment: serverfault/superuser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not necessarily. The OS can detect a USB device without having a driver for it.

Some parts of the USB protocol are device-independent (such as the device reporting to the computer as a USB device, including its name). This will work even without a driver.

So if you want to know if CentOS has detected it properly, you'll have to try accessing its functionality to see if it works.